# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string while transforming RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

**RDD**

```
scala> val rdd = sc.parallelize(List(("A",1), ("A",2), ("B",1), ("A",3), ("B",2)))
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int)] = ParallelCollectionRDD[806] at parallelize at <console>:30
```

**Transformation**

```
scala> rdd.map(r => r.toString.split(',')).map(r => (r(0), r(1).toInt)).collect()
```

I get following error while transforming this RDD using map:

```
17/08/12 12:22:18 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 2.0 in stage 161.0 (TID 7031)
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1)"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to convert `1)` to a number when the extra parenthesis is causing a NumberFormatException.

Try changing `r.toString.split(',').map(r => (r(0), r(1).toInt)).collect()` to just `r.map(r => (r(0), r(1).toInt)).collect()` and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

Your final step suggests that you are creating `RDD[Tuple2(String, Int)]`

But your first step has already created `RDD[tuple2(String, Int)]` which is a `tuple` and in *scala* getting elements of a `tuple` is done by .`_1 , ._2` etc.

```
scala> val rdd = sc.parallelize(List(("A",1), ("A",2), ("B",1), ("A",3), ("B",2)))
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int)] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:25
```

So I guess you won't need `.toInt` in the second parameter as its already an `Int`. So doing following should work

```
scala> rdd.map(r => (r._1, r._2)).collect
res0: Array[(String, Int)] = Array((A,1), (A,2), (B,1), (A,3), (B,2))
```

If you still include `.toInt`, it will still work

```
scala> rdd.map(r => (r._1, r._2.toInt)).collect
res1: Array[(String, Int)] = Array((A,1), (A,2), (B,1), (A,3), (B,2))
```

**So converting the tuple2 to String and splitting the string to transform to the original form would, I guess, be for testing purpose only.**

If thats the reason then, when the `tuple2` is converted to `String` by `.toString` `(` and `)` brackets are also included which need to be removed. So the correct way to do your second step would be

```
scala> rdd.map(r => r.toString().replaceAll("[()]", "").split(",")).map(r => (r(0), r(1).toInt)).collect
res2: Array[(String, Int)] = Array((A,1), (A,2), (B,1), (A,3), (B,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you shouldn't use toString :) From your code:

```
rdd.map(r => r.toString.split(','))
```

Here tuples `(A, B)` are mapped to String `(A, B)`, then you split it into `(A` and `B)`.  What's quite funny, rdd fast already type `RDD[(String, Int)]` :)

Instead you should not use toString and this map function. You can also do :

```
rdd.map(r=> r.toString.replaceAll("(", "").replaceAll(")", "").split(","))
```

So you will replace () with blank strings from input String